# Unable to test Lambda Integration on API Gateway Console

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

It seems like AWS updated the UI for API Gateway.

In the new console, I can not find how to test a Lambda integration.

**How can I test the Lambda Integration from the Console?**

I set up the permissions and routes correctly.

I can successfully call the Lambda function by code or from the terminal

**Stage view**
[image: Console]

**Integration view**
[image: Console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you created is `HTTP API`. Per AWS documentation, `HTTP API` does not have option to test integrations from the console. That is available only for `REST API`. You can see differences in [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-vs-rest.html)

Answer (score -1):

AWS API Gateway needs to **Deploy** it once, like a service.

Any followup changes on the API documents requires another deployment.